# getLastKnownLocation can't get new data by location.setLatitude/setLongitude?

Tags: android, geolocation, location

My full code
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6dd0f33270cc4f46149e

In line 110~131 I want to change the location, it does work, the mapview will change

```
private class MapClickedListener implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick (View v) {
        String lng = "121.558561";
        lng = edt_lng.getText().toString().trim();
        String lat = "25.031005";
        lat = edt_lat.getText().toString().trim();
        if(lng.equals("")||lat.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "input again！", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
            updateToNewLocation(location);
        }else{
            Location location = new Location(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            location.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(lng));
            location.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(lat));
            updateToNewLocation(location);
        }

    }

}
```

On line 133~148, I want to know distance between ***location*** and a point I set

```
private Button.OnClickListener EQ = new Button.OnClickListener(){   
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v) {
        eqlocation.setLongitude(120.82);
        eqlocation.setLatitude(23.85);
        location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        float[] result = new float[5];
        Location.distanceBetween(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), eqlocation.getLatitude(), eqlocation.getLongitude(), result);
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(result[0]);
        BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        double dis = rounded.doubleValue();
        String dist = String.valueOf(dis/1000);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "distance： " + dist + "km", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

};
```

But the result is wrong when I change the location by line 110~131's code.
What should I do to get the right result?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried distanceTo() and checked if you get any better results?, I ususally use distanceTo() with good results.